# How to solve AppCompatActivity (android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity) symbol?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

After installing Android Studio [2.2.3 version] I started a new project, and then after clicking on 'NEXT' i selected tablet&phone and then i clicked on 4.4 android version(kitkat) then I clicked on finish button.
Then this problem raised. I uploaded the screenshots down here.

[image]

Comment: where is screenshot ?

Comment: upload your gradle code also

Answer (score 0):

Add this to build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}
```

There are also has typo in your screenshot. 
Is `AppCompatActivity` not `AppCompatActivit`

Answer (score 0):

There are about 4 probabilities which make the problem arise:

1. **No internet connection**
   When you creating your first project in Android Studio, all the dependencies not yet downloaded to your computer. So, you need to make sure your computer is connected to the internet.
2. **You're behind the proxy**
   If you're behind the proxy, you need to setup the Android Studio to connect via the proxy.
3. **Android Studio is blocked by the firewall**
   Whitelist the Android Studio in your firewall.
4. **Android Studio is blocked by the Anti-Virus**
   Whitelist the Android Studio in your Anti-Virus.